# i need upload a file in Chrome and need **post** some params at the same request

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

i need upload a file in Chrome, and need **post** some params at the same request, and need Basic Authentication.
i want use javascript AJAX to do this.
but chrome do not support sendAsBinary, how can i do this?

```
function sendMsg(status){

    var user = localStorage.getObject(CURRENT_USER_KEY);
    var file = $("#imageFile")[0].files[0];

    var boundary = '----multipartformboundary' + (new Date).getTime();
    var dashdash = '--';
    var crlf     = '\r\n';

    /* Build RFC2388 string. */
    var builder = '';

    builder += dashdash;
    builder += boundary;
    builder += crlf;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var upload = xhr.upload;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState==4){
            //
        }
    };

　　if(upload){
        upload.onprogress = function(ev){
            onprogress(ev);
        };
    }

    /* Generate headers. [STATUS] */            
    builder += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"';
    builder += crlf;
    builder += crlf; 

    /* Append form data. */
    builder += msg;
    builder += crlf;

    /* Write boundary. */
    builder += dashdash;
    builder += boundary;
    builder += crlf;

    /* Generate headers. [PIC] */            
    builder += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pic"';
    if (file.fileName) {
      builder += '; filename="' + file.fileName + '"';
    }
    builder += crlf;

    builder += 'Content-Type: '+file.type;
    builder += crlf;
    builder += crlf; 

    /* Append binary data. */
    builder += file.getAsBinary(); //chrome do not support getAsBinary()
    builder += crlf;

    /* Write boundary. */
    builder += dashdash;
    builder += boundary;
    builder += crlf;

    /* Mark end of the request. */
    builder += dashdash;
    builder += boundary;
    builder += dashdash;
    builder += crlf;

    xhr.open("POST", apiUrl.sina.upload, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth_header(user.userName, user.password));
    xhr.sendAsBinary(builder); //chrome do not support sendAsBinary()

    xhr.onload = function(event) { 
        /* If we got an error display it. */
        if (xhr.responseText) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xhr.send(FormData)`. You don't need to construct the `multipart-form-data` yourself :)
See my response here:

[Javascript/HTML5 file API reading sequential files into multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362747/javascript-html5-file-api-reading-sequential-files-into-multipart-form-data/6048522#6048522)

Answer (score 0):

> builder += file.getAsBinary();
>   //chrome do not support getAsBinary()

Use the `readAsBinaryString` method of the `FileReader` API. Chrome does support it.

> xhr.sendAsBinary(builder); //chrome do
>   not support sendAsBinary()

Learn how to accomplish it at the following URLs:

http://javascript0.org/wiki/Portable_sendAsBinary

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35705

Answer (score -1):

Use a form to submit the file upload request just like you would normally, but set the target of the form to a hidden iframe. This will not refresh the page, but will still upload the file. You can also have the server spit out some JavaScript code which, once loaded into the hidden iframe, will tell you when the file is uploaded. Here's the form:

```
<iframe name=UploadTarget style="visibility: hidden;"></iframe>
<form method=post target=MyHiddenIframe action="Upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type=file name=File1>
  <input type=button value="Upload">
</form>
```

To post some additional params, I have found the easiest way was to append them to the form's action string:

```
Upload.php?MyVar1=value1&MyVar2=value2
```

As far as I know there's no way to read form data and file data in the same request, but you can read from the information sent through the URL.

Comment: THS.but this way i cat not set the Basic Authentication

Comment: @QLeelulu - I don't see why not. Just encode the username:password combination as usual and append it to the form's action string. The users will never see the posted URL (if that's what you're worried about) so it shouldn't be any less secure than other ways.

Comment: the url like this 'http://username:password@stackoverflow.com' in chrome will not send the Basic Authentication info.

Comment: the OP has the file data in javascript in memory, not in a form input. so this does not work